# Extend Custom Block_Sales_Order_View

Tags: magento-1.9

We want to display custom button "**Generate bluedart shipment**" in Sales > Order view page. so we installed custom module in fresh site, it worked fine.

here we used `class Bluedart_Shipment_Block_Sales_Order_View extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View`

[image]

In another site we used same module, but here another module is already extending default Sales Order view to display **Delete Order** button as `class Raveinfosys_Deleteorder_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View` So here "**Generate Bluedart shipment button**" is not displaying....

[image]

app/code/community/**Bluedart**/Shipment/Block/Sales/Order/View.php :

```
class Bluedart_Shipment_Block_Sales_Order_View extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            $itemscount     = 0;
            $totalWeight    = 0;
            $_order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id'));               
            $itemsv = $_order->getAllVisibleItems();
            foreach($itemsv as $itemvv){
                if($itemvv->getQtyOrdered() > $itemvv->getQtyShipped()){
                    $itemscount += $itemvv->getQtyOrdered() - $itemvv->getQtyShipped();
                }
                if($itemvv->getWeight() != 0){
                    $weight =  $itemvv->getWeight()*$itemvv->getQtyOrdered(); 
                } else {
                    $weight =  0.5*$itemvv->getQtyOrdered();
                }
                $totalWeight    += $weight;
             }

             $shipments = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_shipment_collection')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*') 
                ->addFieldToFilter("order_id",$_order->getId())->join("sales/shipment_comment",'main_table.entity_id=parent_id','comment')->addFieldToFilter('comment', array('like'=>"%{$_order->getIncrementId()}%"))->load();

                $bluedart_return_button = false;

                if($shipments->count()){
                    foreach($shipments as $key=>$comment){
                        if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0') <= 0) {
                            $awbno=substr($comment->getComment(),0, strpos($comment->getComment(),"- Order No")); 
                        }
                        else{               
                            $awbno=strstr($comment->getComment(),"- Order No",true);
                        }
                        $awbno=trim($awbno,"AWB No.");                  
                        break;
                    }
                    if((int) $awbno)
                        $bluedart_return_button = true;
                }

            if($_order->canShip()){
             $this->_addButton('create_bluedart_shipment', array(
                            'label'     => Mage::helper('Sales')->__('Generate Blue Dart Shipment'),
                            'onclick'   => 'bluedartpop('.$itemscount.')',
                            'class'     => 'go'
                        ), 0, 100, 'header', 'header');
            }
            elseif(!$_order->canShip() && $bluedart_return_button){
                 $this->_addButton('create_bluedart_shipment', array(
                            'label'     => Mage::helper('Sales')->__('Return Blue Dart Shipment'),
                            'onclick'   => 'bluedartreturnpop('.$itemscount.')',
                            'class'     => 'go'
                  ), 0, 100, 'header', 'header');
            }

                parent::__construct();
        }
    }
```

app/code/community/**Raveinfosys/Deleteorder**/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/View.php

```
class Raveinfosys_Deleteorder_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View 
{
    public function  __construct() {

        parent::__construct();
        $message = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Are you sure you want to delete this order?');
        $this->_addButton('button_id', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('Sales')->__('Delete Order'),
            'onclick'   => 'deleteConfirm(\''.$message.'\', \'' . $this->getDeleteUrl() . '\')',
            'class'     => 'go'
        ), 0, 100, 'header', 'header');
    }

    public function getDeleteUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/deleteorder/delete', array('_current'=>true));
    }   

}
```

I tried this code in Bluedart module, but that didt worked for me : `class Bluedart_Shipment_Block_Sales_Order_View extends Raveinfosys_Deleteorder_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View`

Comment: Did you declare new class in your config.xml

Comment: @Kothari seems module developers already declared....  here is config.xml code : https://pastebin.com/b1kNYzsy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both modules are trying to rewrite the same class, you have 2 choices

- Remove the rewrite in the `Raveinfosys/Deleteorder` config file and make sure your `Bluedart_Shipment_Block_Sales_Order_View` class inherits from `Raveinfosys_Deleteorder_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View`
- Use the `<depends>` in your config xml in `app/etc/module` to make your module depend on the Raveinfosys/Deleteorder.

Edit: for below comments Clarity
For the first option - remove

```
<rewrite>
<sales_order_view>Raveinfosys_Deleteorder_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View</sales_order_view>
</rewrite>
```

from the Raveinfosys config xml file.

Comment: I tried 2nd option and added code in `bludedart` module in `app/etc/modules/Bluedart_Shipment.xml`  as `<depends>
                <Mage_Shipping />
                <Mage_Api />
    <Raveinfosys_Deleteorder />
            </depends>` , but now `delete order` button not displaying in `sales> order > view` page, but `generate bluedart shipment` button displaying.....

Comment: full code for :  app/etc/modules/Bluedart_Shipment.xml = >    https://pastebin.com/KXrkBzis

Comment: Does your Bluedart_Shipment_Block_Sales_Order_View class still inherit from Raveinfosys_Deleteorder_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View ?

Comment: No, i guess now  `Bluedart_Shipment_Block_Sales_Order_View` override the `Raveinfosys_Deleteorder_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View`

Comment: also you told me to add <depends> code in `app/etc/module/config.xml` but i added in `app/etc/module/Bluedart_Shipment.xml` file, is that cause the override ?

Comment: That's the correct file. Bluedart_Shipment.xml.

Comment: okay, now instead of displaying both buttons, now `delete order` button not visible, but `generate blue dart shipment button` is visible now.....

Comment: can you help me to try 1st option.... this is `Raveinfosys_Deleteorder` config.xml : https://pastebin.com/wxYkS0b3 & this is `bluedart config.xml` : https://pastebin.com/nBuy5Mfv , please tell what code i need to change in both files.....

Comment: Remove this from the Raveinfosys_Deleteorder config xml     <rewrite>
                <sales_order_view>Raveinfosys_Deleteorder_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View</sales_order_view>
            </rewrite>

Comment: See editted answer for clarity

Comment: yes , now `generate bluedart shipment` button `displaying`..... but `delete order button` hidden..... what changes i need to to display both buttons.....

Comment: Is the Blue dart file inheritting from Raveinfosys_Deleteorder_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View  ?

Comment: no , `bluedart is inheriting from magento default`..... may i make it `class Bluedart_Shipment_Block_Sales_Order_View extends Raveinfosys_Deleteorder_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64221/discussion-between-baby-in-magento-and-john-tranter).